# Old data is returned on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using **TransactionScope** with **nHibernate**. For working with **nested transactions** I have made a helper class along with **TransactionScope** . My **SessionFactory**:

```
 public class SessionFactory
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static ISessionFactory iSessionFactory;
        [ThreadStatic]
        protected static ISession session;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        private static void buildSessionFactory()
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (session == null)
                {
                    if (iSessionFactory == null)
                    {
                        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
                        iSessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                    }
                    if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
                        session.Dispose();
                    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(iSessionFactory.OpenSession());
                    session = iSessionFactory.OpenSession();
                }
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession
        {
            get
            {
                if (session == null || !session.IsOpen)
                {
                    session = null;
                    buildSessionFactory();
                }
                return session;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Configuration** file is named **hibernate.cfg.xml** and is:

```
<configuration>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL55InnoDBDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">connection string here</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
      <mapping assembly="assembly name here"/>
      <!-- Here -->
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
  <system.transactions>
    <machineSettings maxTimeout="00:00:60" />
  </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

Helper class for managing **nested transactions**:

```
  public class TransactionScopeHelper : SessionFactory, iTransactionScopeHelper
    {
        public static int count = 0;
        public TransactionScope getTransactionScope()
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                if (session != null)
                    session.Clear();
            }
            count++;
            return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
        }

        public void complete(TransactionScope tx)
        {
            count--;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                session.Flush();
                session = null;
            }
            tx.Complete();
        }

        public void rollbackTransaction()
        {
            count = 0;
            session = null;
        }
    }
```

Helper class is used **only in services** and **not in repository**
An example of usage of helper in service:

```
public void updateCategory(CategoryDto category_dto)
{
 try
   {
    using (TransactionScope tx = transactionScopeHelper.getTransactionScope())
     {
      //works here
      transactionScopeHelper.complete(tx);
     }
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
    transactionScopeHelper.rollbackTransaction();
    throw;
    }
}
```

An example of function in **repository**:

```
 public T getById(long id)
 {
  ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession;
  return session.Get<T>(id);
 }
```

Whenever I update some **entity** , old data is shown after few refreshes and again after some refresh new data is retrieved. This is almost continuous. Why am I getting this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am stuck in this for a while. Help will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: You are using this in a web setting?  I don't like the [ThreadStatic] and static method usage in your code.   Also I don't know what your mean by you need to use TransactionScope for nested transactions.  In a web context, you have a natural scope, the web request.  you could create a transaction attribute and have it open the transaction OnExecuting of the controller action and then commit/rollback in OnExecuted.

Comment: @Fran sir I have many modules span in different solutions. So I am unable to use session per web request . I had to implement it in business layer.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have seen that when NHibernate behaves oddly, it uses to be some misunderstaing or misuage of it's Session.

Comment: What are you calling by "refreshes"? May you show the code where you saw that behavior? ("old data is shown after few refreshes and again after some refresh new data is retrieved") Do you have an "unit" test of it?

Comment: @heringer sir I don't have unit tests. By refreshes  I meant browser refreshes. While refreshing browser few times, old data and new data comes alternately but not all the time

Answer (score 3):

There is so much "unusual" stuff going on here I barely know where to begin.

`SessionFactory`

NHibernate's session factory is generelly initialized ONCE on application startup (or when first needed) and then that instance will live for the duration of the program and shared among all threads. We would not typically expect to have a separate instance per thread (as ThreadStatic does). Initializing it repeatedly **will** be a severe performance penalty.

buildSessionFactory() will dispose the session if there is one - but it won't get to that code unless session is null, so I don't understand what the intention really is here.

At the end of buildSessionFactory(), iSessionFactory.OpenSession() is called twice! Once should be enough.

You are setting `current_session_context_class` in the configuration file and call CurrentSessionContext.Bind(). So there should be no need for you to maintain your own thread-static session variable. This is what CurrentSessionContext is for.

A session must eventually be disposed. Therefore, calling a method named like `OpenSession` implies that we get a new session that we are responsible for closing. But your own OpenSession() can return the same session many times, making it difficult to understand who exactly is responsible for closing it. Better to name it `CurrentSession` or similar.

`TransactionScopeHelper`

This is also not possible to understand. There is a reference to a variable `session`, but the definition and setting of this variable is not shown. Code is incomplete. At some points the session reference is set to null but no attempt to dispose it is made, which is mandatory.

Calling Clear() on the session will remove all state from the session and make NHibernate lose track of all loaded objects and therefore be unable to perform dirty check and persist automatically. Other code would need to remember to carefully re-add everything.

Code does not show how and when the session, transaction and transaction scope are actually created. Unable to tell if the interactions are proper. Is the session even aware of the transaction scope?

Finally, to answer your question: "Why am I getting this problem?"

Well, I'm sorry, but the whole situation looks like a mess. And messy code equals messy results. Unless of course the issues I mention above result from partial copy-paste that left out important parts.